# Can the user draw a circle on a Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to intercept the following user gestures, and create a circle on the map?

1. User clicks mouse on the desired centerpoint and keeps mouse button down.
2. User extends the radius and lets the mouse button up

Can the API return the geolocation beneath the mouse pointer on `mousedown` and return the geolocation beneath the mouse pointer on `mouseup`?

Answer (score 0):

i think this should help -> http://www.imapbuilder.com/gmap-builder/map-editor-user-guide/add_polygon_rectangle_circle_clickable_area.php, maybe also this -> https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/mvcfun

never needed to do this kind of work, but this is where i would start and also google is your number one friend...

Comment: I am looking for gestures whereby the user can signal "I choose this place".